# JavaFX App working under Intellij but not as jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, java-8, build

I have written a JavaFX program for a school project. Nothing special. But right from the start I've made a big mistake. I chose SDK Version 1.8 for the project.
Now that I'm done I tried to get the jar of my project with build artifacts. That's working, but when ich open the jar nothing happens. After realizing that I used SDK 1.8, I tried copy everything in a new project using JavaFX SDK 13 and JDK 13.
But I cannot run it this way. Just getting the 'usual' JavaFX Error:

```
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java --module-path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk-13.0.1/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=51795:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/target/classes:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk-13.0.1/lib/javafx-swt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk-13.0.1/lib/javafx.base.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk-13.0.1/lib/javafx.controls.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk-13.0.1/lib/javafx.fxml.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk-13.0.1/lib/javafx.graphics.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk-13.0.1/lib/javafx.media.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk-13.0.1/lib/javafx.swing.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk-13.0.1/lib/javafx.web.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/appdirs-1.0.3.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/jna-platform-4.5.2.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/jna-4.5.2.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/Downloads/sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.1.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/javafx-maven-plugin-0.0.3.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.6.0.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/maven-model-3.6.0.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/maven-artifact-3.6.0.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.3.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/cdi-api-1.0.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/plexus-utils-3.1.0.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/plexus-java-0.9.11.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/asm-7.0-beta.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/qdox-2.0-M9.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/plexus-archiver-3.6.0.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/plexus-io-3.0.1.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/commons-io-2.6.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/commons-compress-1.16.1.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/objenesis-2.6.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/snappy-0.4.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/xz-1.8.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/commons-exec-1.3.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/mojo-executor-2.3.0.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.22.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/maven-core-3.6.0.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/maven-settings-3.6.0.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.6.0.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.25.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/maven-builder-support-3.6.0.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.6.0.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/maven-model-builder-3.6.0.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/maven-resolver-provider-3.6.0.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/maven-resolver-impl-1.3.1.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/maven-resolver-api-1.3.1.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/maven-resolver-spi-1.3.1.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/maven-resolver-util-1.3.1.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.3.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/guava-25.1-android.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.7.1.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive - stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/jfoenix-8.0.8.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/13/javafx-controls-13.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/13/javafx-controls-13-mac.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/13/javafx-graphics-13.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/13/javafx-graphics-13-mac.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/13/javafx-base-13.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/13/javafx-base-13-mac.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/13/javafx-fxml-13.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/13/javafx-fxml-13-mac.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/.m2/repository/net/harawata/appdirs/1.0.3/appdirs-1.0.3.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/4.5.2/jna-platform-4.5.2.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.5.2/jna-4.5.2.jar:/Users/marcelschalk/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.28/slf4j-simple-1.7.28.jar" sample.Main
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/marcelschalk/OneDrive%20-%20stud.hs-merseburg.de/Proggen/Manager/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.22.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/marcelschalk/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.28/slf4j-simple-1.7.28.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3230)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:53)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
Exception running application sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't really know what to do now...

These are the Files that are working in Intellij under JDK 1.8:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DTtntPrh-9pkgrwyrHi9im3B2IAYeZoa/view?usp=sharing

And this here is the rebuild project that is not working:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gPRzxV32OAUZct4w1lF-Y3WTv7lR-BCF/view?usp=sharing

> Project Structure:

[image]

Comment: Run the program from the command prompt to see what errors you get. I am guessing that you have some resource that is not in the correct place.

Comment: “Just getting the 'usual' JavaFX Error”  —Please edit your question and show the entire stack trace of that exception, including all “Caused by:” sections.

Comment: Ok Post is edited

Comment: It's a requirement for questions to contain a [mcve] in the question itself. Links to another site or to another post on this site are not sufficient. In your case the part where the fxml loader is initialized and the project structure is required. However if you search for the error message (`Location is required.`) there should already plenty of questions about this and I'm pretty sure theres already an answer that covers your case.

Comment: Your `fxml` file doesn't seem to be included in the jar file: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.`. Are you sure you are running a single jar? In the module system the jar can't be split over multiple files.

Comment: Show your project structure.

Comment: @fabian My project is 2700 lines of code and I have no idea what causes the error. So all I could do is post my whole code and I think that's not a good idea. ;-)
If done some changes but it's still not working. I've used getClass().getClassLoader().getResource instead of getClass().getResource and I made a copy of my picture folder, fxml files (in a fxml directory) and my css file to the resources folder. And I changed the path after getResource to /fxml/example.fxml. Same thing for css: sample/stylesheet.css to /stylesheet.css and the picturefolder to /img. Still "Location is required"

Comment: @Sedrick https://imgur.com/a/QSikPeR

Comment: Ok. After cleaning up the paths for all the fxml and image files, I can finally run the jdk13 version in Intellij. Another problem was the use von jfoenix that doesn't work javafx13. So I swap it with a normal tabPane.
But I still can't build a working jar with maven. Seems like javafx-maven-plugin does not support jdk13. Any other idea what I can do to get a executable jar? -.-

Comment: The fact you have some of your FXML files under `src/main/java` is suspicious. Resources belong under `src/main/resources` when using Maven's _Standard Directory Layout_ (which Gradle also uses by default). I'm not sure how this works at all, even in IntelliJ, as the resource files under `src/main/java` should be ignored by Maven.

Comment: @Slaw Sorry I just copied the files to the resources folder, so that's reason why they're still in the java folder. They're just still there...ignored by Intellij when I run the program.
But like I said, I'm still not able the get a functional jar. Is there any way I can get a functional jar with fxml-files and pics using javafx13?

Comment: The only difference between Java 8 and Java 9+ regarding the retrieval of resources relates to inter-module visibility (i.e. _encapsulation_); since you're not using a module, let alone multiple modules, this difference doesn't affect you. In other words, what was working in Java 8 should be working in Java 13. You must have changed something when copying the project. Without a [mre] (in the question itself), however, helping you will be difficult to impossible. Also, why did you copy the project instead of just update the JDK version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using Java build automation tools to build a project with resources and external libs such as: maven, gradle or ant. I prefer maven.

You can use my template Maven project from [github](https://github.com/Silird/TemplateProject).

All build settings are in the *pom.xml* at the root of the project. The main interest for you is the plugin *maven-shade-plugin* that deals with packaging into jar with all your external dependencies and resources. You need to specify your main class there.
Also, using the maven you do not need to manually download and bind libraries to the project. You only need to specify the lib in the dependencies section. For it just google something like *"library_name maven"*, go to the maven repository, choose version and copy the suggested lines to the dependency section.

I also recommend moving all the images and fxml forms to the project resources. And get it like this:

```
getClass().getResource("/frames/MainFrame.fxml")
```

After you copy all the code into the maven project and configure it, you need:

1. Open configuration drop-down menu near the run and debug buttons.
2. Edit configurations...
3. Press plus button on left upper corner.
4. Choose Maven.
5. In comand line type *clean install*
6. You can rename this configuration by changing Name.
7. Then save this configuration and run it, after run successfuly ended your .jar file will be located at *target* directory.

Comment: Thank you. That really helped me. What also caused the problem, was the fact, that Maven did not include my global library of sqlite-jdbc. I have to add it as a dependency. And I used 
`<include>**/*.fxml</include>
<include>**/*.png</include>
<include>**/*.jpg</include>
<include>**/*.css</include>`
So I don't have to change all the paths in my fxml- and java-files.

Is there a way to get a .dmg or .app file (Mac) and .exe as well in Maven? And with an icon?

Comment: @ata1704, maven is very powerful tool with many plugins. I think some of them can help you. Try google to find maven plugins that can do what you need. I don't know the solution to do this.

Comment: @ata1704, and yes, meven doesn't know about your IDE settings, where you include library. But when you use maven, IDE automaticaly include it in your project.